# script not found after new ownership of googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Morning Hope you had a great weekend. I have a google sheet that I was giving ownership of. that is the only that was changed. when we attempt to run it now, we get the error  (script function (name) could not be found.

1. sheet and script, was owned by employee who left.   I logged into his google and changed the ownership of the sheet to me nothing else
2. it is a monthly back that I am assigned to do, so went to sheet did the back up and there is a step to data to database. (script)
3. click the button and no script found.  ran the script no errors completed fine.  add the script to button no spaces no parentheses.
   still came back with error.

I saw somewhere where it said to have the script authorize.  Don't know if that was broken when I took ownership of the sheet.?
as it doesn't work for any of the 15 people who have edit rights including me. we can do it manually and it work fine also.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the textual error ? Have you tried to remove the button and add a new one?

Comment: HI, I did that and also ran the script with no error in the log. IT seemed to me that it might be a owner issue, but i am not sure. I'm new to this

Comment: don't know if I need to be owner of the script

Comment: Buttons (drawings with an assigned script) only works with bound script... the script ownership is inherited from the container. Try using Chrome in incongnito mode with all the extensions disabled.

Comment: Hey ruben thanks for the tip. I got the same error.  I am trying a work around by adding special menus for the scripts

Comment: IMHO it's more reliable to work with custom menus than with buttons (drawings) as any editor might accidentally break them.

Comment: Hey all. I went the way of menus.  I am the 3rd person to be admin of this spread and it was way to cumbersome to back track what was done with all the buttons. I just took the script and added 1 menu for all to choose their function from, and that worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. You might add some documentation directly in the Apps Script project by using line comments (start with `//`) and block comments (put  comments between `/* and */` or `/**`and `*/`.